# Copy data from one Wordpress Multisite data table to another

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Some guidance as to how to go about this or  via a function (for each user).

Say the data to be copied is FROM

wp_bp_xprofile_data  in   field_id 3   for user_id 21

to be copied TO

wp_9_bp_xprofile_data in   field_id 3   for user_id 21

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easier to dump the table in a first step, then inserting it in a second. You then just have to rename the destination table in the dump before.